# Why is the expected value of the product of standard normals the identity?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

For $Z=(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)^T$ why is the expected value of $ZZ^T$ equal to the identity matrix $I_3$?

When I calculate $ZZ^T$ I get $(Z_1^2+Z_2^2+Z_3^2)$ but the expected value of this is 3 so I’m not sure what’s going wrong.

Comment: Sine $Z$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix and $Z^T$ is $1 \times 3$, their product is a $3\times 3$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $Z_iZ_j$. That's what we're taking the expectation of.

Comment: Looks like you calculated $Z^\top Z$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I_n)$ is normally distributed on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with iid components $Z_i$ then

$$E[ZZ^\top]_{ij} = E[Z_iZ_j] = \delta_{ij}.$$

Comment: @FD_bfa It is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Z_iZ_j)&=\begin{cases}\mathsf E(Z_i^2)&:&i=j\\\mathsf E(Z_i)\mathsf E(Z_j)&:&i\neq j\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}1&:&i=j\\0&:&i\neq j\end{cases}\\[1ex]&=\delta_{ij}\end{align}$$

Comment: A square matrix with Kronecker delta entries is an indentity matrix; since the diagonals will have unit value and the rest will be zero valued.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamKemp I know that $Z_i^2$ is chi square with 1 degree of freedom and so it’s expectation is 1. But what is the reason for the expectation being 0 in the case of $Z_iZ_j$?

Comment: The expectation of a product of *independent* random variables is the product of their expectations, and the expectation of a *standard Normal distributed* random variable is zero. @FD_bfa

Comment: @FD_bfa, it must be an implicit assumption though since jointly normal + uncorrelated implies independent.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio so all jointly normal random variables with standard normal distribution are independent by definition

Comment: @FD_bfa, that is correct